# uint8_t etc as color variable

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, sketch, adafruit

I am very new to coding and I am attempting to teach myself the best I can.  I have no prior knowledge of coding and am filling in the blanks via YouTube and forums alike.  One place I keep getting hung up on is what seems to be an unsigned integer.

I have tried to figure out how these work (assignment and such) to no avail. I was wondering if anyone could offer some insight for me or at the least a link that gets specific for the Arduino.

I see them used as uint8_t, uint16_t, and uint_32 in various places.  Am I correct that it is an unsigned integer?  Meaning it is a whole positive number only.

The code I have attached is from Adafruit's article on multi-tasking.  I am trying to adapt my sketch for millis() over delay().

```
      uint32_t Color1, Color2;  // What colors are in use
      uint16_t TotalSteps;  // total number of steps in the pattern
      uint16_t Index;  // current step within the pattern
```

For instance: on the variable declarations they use these for the color.  I will need to change the colors, but have only seen them expressed in RGB.  They are in every sketch I see, but I am struggling to answer this question on my own.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for information about C types on the internet, there will be much help to find, but effectively you are correct. One format of integer types in C take the form:

`uint` / `int`: Signed or unsigned integer. Unsigned integers are stored in simple binary representation, and signed integers are stored in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form.

`8` / `16` / `32` / `64`: The number of bits to store the value. This means the number of possible values is 2<sup>*x*</sup> where *x* is the number of bits.

`_t`: Simply a suffix to indicate that it is a type name, not a variable.

---

### Colour storage

Colours are generally stored as three components: *red*, *green* and *blue* (or sometimes four, adding *alpha*, the degree of transparency).

If each component is given an unsigned byte to be stored (so it has a value from 0–255), then the total colour size is 24 bits. However, 24 bit integers are not a standard size, so the next bigger size is selected, 32-bit. This also allows room for an alpha component if necessary, but otherwise the spare 8 bits are unused.

#### For example:

```
| 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000000  | = 32 bits
| red      | green    | blue     |alpha/empty|
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The breakdown helps to simplify it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Everything about standard integer types is in [`<stdint.h>`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html)